# How to get a list of windows in X11 with Go

Tags: go, x11, xlib, xserver

I would like to get a list of windows + window names of all open windows in X11 using go. I assume that the xgb package would be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use C and thus list all windows:

```
/*
Window *getDisplayWindows (Display *disp, unsigned long *len);

Window *getDisplayWindows (Display *disp, unsigned long *len) {
    Atom prop = XInternAtom(disp,"_NET_CLIENT_LIST",False), type;
    int form;
    unsigned long remain;
    unsigned char *list;
    if (XGetWindowProperty(disp,XDefaultRootWindow(disp),prop,0,1024,False,XA_WINDOW,
                &type,&form,len,&remain,&list) != Success) {
        return 0;
    }
    return (Window*)list;
}
*/
import "C"

//your go code below
```

I used this for a [package of mine](https://github.com/audrenbdb/goforeground/blob/main/fg_x11.go) to put a window foreground. Hope it helps ?